# Why does StackTrace.GetFrames() return array of nullable StackFrame?

Tags: c#, .net

After I enabled nullable reference types in my project I've noticed that `Stack.GetFrames()` method returns `StackFrame?[]`.

I assume it is possible to get an array which contains nulls at some indices. But in which case will this happen?

Comment: It won't happen.  If you run on a wonky custom host then you'd already know things might not work as you'd expect.  SO will be fascinated by it, be sure to tell us.

Comment: Then why such weird signature?

Comment: Progress is slow, but being made in .net 5 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/#nullability-annotation-improvements

Comment: Looks like `StackTrace.GetFrames` has been updated in .net 5 https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StackTrace.cs,158.